# Accessing data between jar files with two different processes

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, websphere

I have 4 applications in running websphere application server,one as ear file and other 3 based on message driven beansas jar files . Now i am trying to add one more application i.e jar file this application will start up on server and keep all the data in hashmap object. i want to read this hashmap object using 4th application api  through one of the message driven bean code.

Is it possible to read 4th application hashmap object without RMI call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want some sort of singleton service which will be utilized by the other apps on the app server.  You can implement this as a [`@Singleton`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/Singleton.html) ejb, which can then be accessed by other apps using standard ejb invocation methods.

Comment: singleton service you are taking about is not based on EJB.So how can i call in this case?

Comment: are you saying that the current service you have implemented is not an ejb?  if so, then why not make it one?

Comment: @  jtahlborn : This is third party jar .So that code i cna't chnage it.So with EJB not possible right?So only option is RMI? .Any other approaches.

Comment: @user2610401 - you can build your _own_ ejb which includes the third-party jar in question.